# List of wars someone could be a part of, if they were born a certain date

Tags: resources

I am trying to do research on a "military" character for a novel I am writing. I want him to have a great deal of combat experience, and in and out of many tours and wars.  I am hoping I can have a resource that I can use to put in someones birthday, and get a list of all the wars they could have potentially done duty for.

I am thinking of making him around the age of 43. I definitely know he would have gone on Iraq tours...I have heard of military guys doing two tours in iraq, did the time period make it possible to allow for more?  If someone was say...43, what wars could have they have participated in, and how many tours each?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried googling "wars between 1990 and 2014" (1990 being the age your character would have been 18)? There's a whole book on that very specific topic called *War in the Modern World, 1990-2014 not to mention that you can find lists of wars by date on Wikipedia. Also, tours of duty are going to depend largely on the kind of tour and the branch of service, as well as the country.

Comment: Actually your suggestion worked. Put that as an answer, and I will mark it as accepted answer, or I can. I did that and was able to get a full list, easily. It gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about because it is not about writing

Comment: @CLockeWork: In case of such specific - focused questions, our policy is to direct the asker towards the right place where the answer can be found before closing. So - yes, the question should be closed as off-topic (now that the right resource was found) but that doesn't mean it's unwelcome here.

Comment: I agree in general @SF., though obviously Google is the right source for this specific question and I'd generally expect people to have already been there.